# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up') when using withStyle HOC MUI 5

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, higher-order-components, themeprovider

Recently migrated my code from MUI v4 to v5, Jest not able to find 'theme' in my`style.js` file, getting this error while running test cases, please find the code snippit below.

NOTE: My parent component is wrapped with themeProvider as this was working fine with MUI v4.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')

       9 |    
    > 11 |     [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
         |                        ^
      12 |       width: "calc(100% - 400px)",
      13 |     },
      14 |     [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
```

**Child.js**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles";
import withStyles from '@mui/styles/withStyles';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Child = () => {
   -----my code ---------- 
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(Child));
```

**style.js**

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
 contents: {
   display: "flex",
   justifyContent: "center",
   [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
     width: "calc(100% - 400px)",
   },
   [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
     width: "calc(100% - 360px)",
   },  }
});
export default styles;
```

Rendering the component like this in test file.

**Child.test.js**

```
   const { baseElement, rerender, getByTestId } = render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <Child {...props} />
     </Provider>,
     { wrapper: MemoryRouter }
```

Comment: Do you think test have the reference of theme or breakpoints. I think the problem is test environment doesn't have the reference of theme breakpoints

Comment: Yes, theme breakpoints are working fine on UI, but this was working fine with MUI v4 without any jest config. i have figured out the work around which is importing theme from creatingTheme inside style.js file. But there are more than 100 style.js files, so manually changing will be tedious